# homebank layout broken

Tags: layout

Main screen layout in Homebank 4.6.2 is broken et start up.
If I adjust the layout, It does not retain and screen is messy when I launch the program.
I trashed homebank preferences in /home/user/.config/homebank but it doesn't help.

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was solved in Homebank update 4.6.3.